WiFi card not detected on Ubuntu 20.04 (Dual Boot)
I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside with my Windows 11 on my desktop computer. However, it says that there is no WiFi adapter.
I dug into a lot of solutions, yet not fixed.
I already turned off windows Fast Boot + I already disabled Secure Boot
To give an overview of what is the problem:
When I type sudo lshw -C network, it gives me:
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f6600000-f66fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 05
       serial: 74:56:3c:ca:e7:56
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-124-generic firmware=rtl8125b-2_0.0.2 07/13/20 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:39 ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f6500000-f650ffff memory:f6510000-f6513fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:5
       logical name: wlx502b73cb16b1
       serial: 50:2b:73:cb:16:b1
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=5.15.0-124-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.20.0.9 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11

It's obvious that my WiFi card is not being detected, since it's UNCLAIMED.
As I was trying to install backport-iwlwifi-dkms, I faced the issue that my current kernel/arch is not suitable for this package:
~$ uname -r
5.15.0-124-generic

Therefore, I believe that my kernel version caused this issue.
Lastly, I faced the same issue with my newly purchased Alienware X16 R2, as its WiFi card was UNCLAIMED as well.
The main difference between my desktop and my laptop is the WiFi card's version.
My desktop has Realtek WiFi card and Intel is what is mounted on my laptop.
Please let me know if there is anything need to be addressed to find the best solution.

What is your Wifi card model?

My motherboard's model is GIGABYTE B650 AORUS Elite AX AMD B650 ATX. The Wi-Fi model should be Intel® Wi-Fi 6E AX210 according to Gigabyte's website.

I'm pretty sure that there is something wrong for the Wi-Fi cards designed in the last 1 or 2 years and the Ubuntu 20.04's kernel ...
The same configuration is working perfectly on our Lab desktop computer (which has been purchased like 4 years ago), but neither my desktop or the Alienware x16 r2's Wi-Fi cards are working.
The whole point of sticking to Ubuntu 20.04 was to use ROS noetic for my case. At this point, I just ended up migrating to Ubuntu 22.04 and archiving my noetic workspace within a docker container ...
